# WApplication::bind() usage in combination with Wt::WServer::post

Tags: wt

I want to bind a callback, which will be called by a thread outside the Wt event loop.
So obviously I want to use Wt::WServer::post, but I don't get how WApplication::bind should be used, since it's a nonstatic function.
First attempt was this:

```
auto loaded_callback = [](const decltype(Wt::WApplication::sessionId) &session){
    Wt::WServer::post(session, 
Wt::WApplication::bind(&table_model::member_func),)
};
```

Which of course didn't work because `bind` is nonstatic. However my next attempt

```
auto object_protect_bind = 
Wt::WApplication::instance()->bind(&order_aggregate_table_model::load_future_in_map);
```

failed with a shitload of compiler errors

> Error  153 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   \boost\function\function_template.hpp   922 1   MDDB_Web
>   Error  156 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   \boost\function\function_template.hpp   926 1   MDDB_Web
>   Error  160 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   \boost\function\function_template.hpp   927 1   MDDB_Web
>   Error  150 error C2903: 'apply' : symbol is neither a class template nor a function template   \boost\function\function_template.hpp   922 1   MDDB_Web
>   Error  162 error C2825: 'manager_type': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::' \boost\function\function_template.hpp   934 1   MDDB_Web
>   Error  154 error C2653: 'handler_type' : is not a class or namespace name  \boost\function\function_template.hpp   926 1   MDDB_Web
>   Error  158 error C2653: 'handler_type' : is not a class or namespace name  \boost\function\function_template.hpp   927 1   MDDB_Web
>   Error  164 error C2275: 'manager_type' : illegal use of this type as an expression \boost\function\function_template.hpp   934 1   MDDB_Web
>   Error  165 error C2146: syntax error : missing '}' before identifier 'manage'  \boost\function\function_template.hpp   934 1   MDDB_Web
>   Error  159 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'manager_type'    \boost\function\function_template.hpp   927 1   MDDB_Web
>   Error  155 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'invoker_type'    \boost\function\function_template.hpp   926 1   MDDB_Web
>   Error  152 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'  \boost\function\function_template.hpp   922 1   MDDB_Web
>   Error  163 error C2039: 'manage' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' \boost\function\function_template.hpp   934 1   MDDB_Web
>   Error  151 error C2039: 'apply' : is not a member of 'boost::detail::function::get_invoker0'  \boost\function\function_template.hpp   922 1   MDDB_Web
>   Error  166 error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation \boost\function\function_template.hpp   934 1   MDDB_Web

while the overall solution I had in mind was:

```
auto sessionId = Wt::WApplication::instance()->sessionId();
auto server_ptr = Wt::WServer::instance();

auto object_protect_bind = Wt::WApplication::instance()->bind(&order_aggregate_table_model::load_future_in_map);
auto inner_bind = std::bind(object_protect_bind, this);
auto loaded_callback = [] 
    (Wt::WServer* server,
    const std::string &session,
    boost::function<void()> widget_bind)
-> void {
    server->post(session, widget_bind, boost::function<void()>());
};

this->data_future =
    std::async(std::launch::async,
    table_model::load_quiet_a_bunch_of_data,
    query, database, std::bind(loaded_callback, server_ptr, sessionId, inner_bind));
Wt::WTimer::singleShot(20 * 1000, this, &table_model::load_future_in_map);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Koen Deforche in the official forum](http://redmine.webtoolkit.eu/boards/2/topics/11348?r=11355#message-11355), the problem was:
 `Wt::WApplication::bind` is supposed to take the already binded method, not the method itself.

Also there is a surprising (for me at least) template detail when using lambdas, so for the sake of an example, my solution for a callback, used by a data loading thread, is:

```
static std::map<decltype(views::measurements_grouped_by_orders::order_number),
    order_value> 
    order_aggregate_table_model::async_load_order_values(
    const odb::query<views::measurements_grouped_by_orders> &query,
    std::shared_ptr<odb::database> mddb,
    std::function<void(void)> callback) {...
    if (callback){ callback(); }
    return map;
    }

void order_aggregate_table_model::get_data(const odb::query<views::measurements_grouped_by_orders> &query){

auto sessionId = Wt::WApplication::instance()->sessionId();
auto server_ptr = Wt::WServer::instance();

auto object_protect_bind = 
    Wt::WApplication::instance()->bind(/*Wt::WApplication::bind
                                       handles the case that 
                                       the widget might already been destroyed*/
        std::bind(&order_aggregate_table_model::load_future_in_map,this));
auto loaded_callback = [] 
    (Wt::WServer* server,
    const std::string &session,
    std::function<void()> widget_bind)
-> void {
    server->post(session, widget_bind, boost::function<void()>()); 
    //Wt::Server::post handles the case when the session is already been destroyed
};
std::function<void()> final_callback = //Because of template quirks had to stick the type
    std::bind(loaded_callback, server_ptr, sessionId, object_protect_bind);
this->order_aggregate_map_future =
    std::async(std::launch::async,
    order_aggregate_table_model::async_load_order_values,
    query, this->mddb, final_callback);

Wt::WTimer::singleShot(30 * 1000, this, 
    &order_aggregate_table_model::load_future_in_map); //For the case that the async loader crashed
    }
```